# Supporting certain orientations only not working in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I can't simply uncheck in the *Deployment Orientation* section because i have a view that must be viewed in landscape mode, and when I leave landscape mode unchecked while it works  in the first few view to keep my views only portrait, when I get to the view that forces it to be landscape it crashes.

So with that being said, all orientation possibilities are checked on the *Deployment Information* and I am using the following code to keep my views portrait:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
    }

    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that this does not seem to be working in iOS 7, or in the iOS 6 simulator for that matter, although it works well in my physical iPhone with iOS 6, but again, not on the iPhone with iOS 7.

What can be a solution to this problem?